# Php - seperate full hour interval from quarter hour interval array

Tags: php, time, intervals

Currently i have $quarterHrIntervalArr i.e 15 min interval array where 19:15 is start time & 22:45 is end time.

```
19:15
19:30
19:45
20:00
20:15
20:30
20:45
21:00
21:15
21:30
21:45
22:00
22:15
22:30
22:45
```

How can i seperate complete hr from above array like 20-21 = 20hr & 21-22 = 21hr is complete hour, how can i remove complete hr intervals from $quarterHrIntervalArr and store in $hrIntervalArr.

So that final two array would be like

```
$quarterHrIntervalArr = [19:15,19:30,19:45,22:00,22:15,22:30,22:45]

$hrIntervalArr = [20:00,21:00]; // Note 22:00 is not added because its not complete hr as 23:00 is not endtime.
```

Comment: 20:15 to 21:15 is also a one hour interval

Comment: yes @jsotola but i have to consider HH:00-HH:00 as complete hr.

Comment: Will the gap always be 15 mins?

Comment: yes @nice_dev 15 min gap.

Comment: @Rahul_Dange Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert to timestamp. after that, timestamp % 3600, if result == 0 then it is H:00.

This is my example:

```
<?php

$quarterHrIntervalArr = [
"19:15",
"19:30",
"19:45",
"20:00",
"20:15",
"20:30",
"20:45",
"21:00",
"21:15",
"21:30",
"21:45",
"22:00",
"22:15",
"22:30",
"22:45"
];

$res = [];
foreach ($quarterHrIntervalArr as $key => $value) {
    $time = strtotime($value)%3600; // check time is H:00
    if($time == 0)
    {
        $res[] = $value;
    }
}
array_pop($res);

var_dump($res); // ["20:00", "21:00"]
```

Comment: ok but how can we remove complete hour intervals from $quarterHrIntervalArr  without extra loop?

Comment: @Rahul_Dange unset them in for loop above.

Comment: Also array_pop used to removed unwanted 23:00 hr which was not part of  $quarterHrIntervalArr.

Comment: using regex with example 
`$pattern = "/\d\d:00/";

preg_match_all($pattern, json_encode($quarterHrIntervalArr),$matches);
array_pop($matches[0]);

var_dump($matches[0]);exit;`